# Few Jquery Plugin Functions are missing in IE9 - Object doesn't support property or method

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, knockout.js

I am getting the following error only in IE 9 Browser.

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method  File:
>   Knockout-3.1.0.js

Some of my Jquery Plugin methods are not loading in IE 9. I can see the jquery functions which are available in the ____Proto____ of DOM Elements in IE 10 are missing for the DOM Elements in IE9. I am using these jquery functions inside the knockout custom binding handlers. For Example I am using `$(element).autosize()`.

It is working fine in IE 10 but not in IE 9.

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? In the 2.x branch some features which supported older IE browsers were removed. Try 1.11 if you aren't already.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan According to [this](http://jquery.com/browser-support/) jQuery 2.x supports IE 9